# Push array of an object to array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

```
    const [ post, setPost] = useState([])

    function addMemo() {
        let memo = [
                { id:1, name:'shyam', post:'developer' },
                { id:2, name:'ram', post:'porter' },
                { id:3, name:'prakash', post:'cobler' },
                { id:4, name:'sanj', post:'designer' },
                { id:5, name:'anil', post:'pilot' },
                { id:6, name:'gopal', post:'laptain' }
            ]
        
        setPost( [...post, memo] )
     }

    return (
         <button type="button" onClick={() => addMemo()}>Click Me</button>
   )
```

here is my code but I could not push array of object to the existing array Push array of an object to existing array,

Comment: @william's anser is correct but just fyi you should reference your addMemo and not rebind it on every call like onClick={addMemo}

Comment: I also met this kind of problem. I tried the below method but now working.

Answer (score 2):

Use `...` spread operator for the `memo`.

```
    setPost( [...post, ...memo] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are updating state based on previous state it is better to pass a function to the setState function.

```
setPost((prevPost) => [...prevPost, memo] )
```